How do I organise two div's next to each other with 100% height
I am trying to make dashboard using CSS but div's are overlapping each other and some time not showing at all. If I use position fixed and fix height then works fine but I want to have 100% height for both of them. Anyone help me on this issue please with pure css


.header {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(208, 208, 211);
  height: 50px;
}

.cont {
  display: table-cell;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(115, 115, 214);
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content-area {
  background: rgb(182, 192, 126);
  width: 550px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
<div class="header">
</div>

<div class="cont">
  <div class="sidebar">
  </div>

  <div class="content-area">
  </div>
</div>



I have tried display: inline-block; and other properties like fixing height property, position property, It works with fixed height but that is not required
